# CanceledError with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, vite

I am following this tutorial
[React Login Authentication with JWT Access, Refresh Tokens, Cookies and Axios](https://stackoverflow.com)

on time 32:28 you can follow along to see how the original code works.

this is the react frontend code on github:
https://github.com/tanvircr7/React-Auth-JS

this is the nodejs backend code:
https://github.com/tanvircr7/user_auth

[image: Console Error]

****Below is the Users.jsx file in the frontend code. If the refreshtoken is valid we get a new refresh token from the backend.****
**On my code the employee list is being shown even with the error in the image shown above. But if I uncomment that navigate line after the console.log the code get's into an infinite loop of login pages.**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useAxiosPrivate from "../hooks/useAxiosPrivate";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState();
    const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        const controller = new AbortController();

        const getUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axiosPrivate.get("/users", {
                    signal: controller.signal,
                });
                console.log(`${response.data} <- reponse data for try block`);
                isMounted && setUsers(response.data);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                console.log("ERROR CAUGHT");
                // navigate("/login", { state: { from: location }, replace: true });
            }
        };

        getUsers();

        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <article>
            <h2>Users List</h2>
            {users?.length ? (
                <ul>
                    {users.map((user, i) => (
                        <li key={i}>{user?.username}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            ) : (
                <p>No users to display</p>
            )}
        </article>
    );
};

export default Users;
```

**it seems an error is being caught inside userEffect() where the try block is failing**